# Access to office 2003 files

Tags: c#, c++, .net, extract, office-2003

I want to access to office 2003 files (.doc, .xls and .ppt) in order to extract text and some metadata (number of words, number of sheets, pictures, template, etc.). I'm able to do it with Open XML SDK for office 2007 documents. However, this extracton will take place on a server, which can't have apps like Microsoft Office installed (that's the reason why I can't use Office's Interop).
I have tried NPOI, however actually it only supports .xls files. The other libraries that I found are not open-source, I can't use it on my work... I downloaded NPOI Scratchpad but the code is very "raw", I can't use it on my work.
Do you have any other idea to get the text and metadata from office 2003 documents? I'm not a very experienced programmer, and I'm using C# (However, if there is any solution to this problem in C++ I could consider to use it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries like:

- ClosedXML (Office 2007)
- EPPlus (Office 2007)
- Aspose cells(Office 97-2010, I use this one)

I don't know any free libraries supporting office 2003 format.

good luck